# Dart Angular Route Parameters not working

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to get AngularDart routing to work properly and it's giving me a headache.  I'm trying to get the query parameter of a child route and it's not working in my component when extending OnActivate like [the tutorial here says](https://angulardart.dev/guide/router/3).  It recognizes the page but it doesn't give me the parameter in the RouterState.  I don't know why.  I get no errors and I get no warnings or anything.  I can bypass it using `Uri` class for now to test other things and to keep my momentum but I would prefer to have it working as expected.

This is the structure:

```
Top
 - /routes.dart
 - /route_paths.dart
 - /resources_list_component.dart
 - /resources
   - ./resources_routes.dart
   - ./resources_route_paths.dart
   - ./my_resource_component.dart
   - ./my_resource_component.html
```

In `/route_paths.dart` I have

```
static final resources = RoutePath(path: 'resources');
```

Which is then used in `/routes.dart`:

```
static final resources = RouteDefinition(
  routePath: RoutePaths.resouces
  component: resource_list_template.ResourceListComponentNgFactory
);
```

I then use this route as the parent router in my resources route paths file:

```
static final resource = RoutePath(
  path: 'resource/:id',
  parent: _parent.RoutePaths.resources
);
```

In the above snippet, you can see that I'm expecting RouterState to have the query parameter `id` as is suggested in AngularDart's documentation.  This allows me to do something like this: `http://localhost/#/resources/resource/1`

This router path is then used in `resources/resources_routes.dart`:

```
    static final resource = RouteDefinition(
        routePath: ResourcesRoutePaths.resource,
        component: my_resource_template.MyResourceComponentNgFactory,
    );

    static final all = <RouterDefinition>[ resource ];
```

All this works, almost.  When I go to the url `/resources/resource/1`, i indeed see the correct HTML output from `my_resource_component.html` so I know that Angular Routing is working up to that point.  The kicker is in trying to get `/1` to be query parameter with the name "id".

In the documentation for it says I need to extend the component with OnActivate which is specific to the lifecycle of the app.  So I do this and add the following method to the controller:

```
@Component(...)
class MyResourceComponent extends OnActivate {
    ...
    @override
    OnActivate (RouterState _, RouterState current) {
       Console().log(current.queryParameters.isEmpty);
    }
}
```

The above code outputs `true`.  As in the queryParameters are empty.  I have followed the guides and at this point I don't know what I'm missing.  Does someone know why this could happen, or if there's a glaring step I'm missing??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to access `queryParameters` instead of `parameters`.

`Console().log(current.queryParameters.isEmpty);`

vs

`Console().log(current.parameters.isEmpty);`

https://angulardart.dev/api/angular_router/angular_router/RouterState/parameters

The `parameters` map returns the URL parameters whereas the `queryParameters` map returns the query parameters.  For instance, given the url:

`/resources/resource/1?hey=dude`

"1" is a url parameter where "hey" is a query parameter.